# Is it possible to initialize characters to a number, n, based on how many characters the user inputs?

Tags: c++, string, char, initialization

I had a homework question where I had to ask the user for a character and use that character to create the image of the letter C. It sparked an interest and I wanted to try and make a program that asks the user for a letter, word, or sentence of their choice and have it create the letter, word, or sentence out of a character they choose. For exmaple if the user inputs "Hi" with the character X, the out put would be:

```
X  X   X
X  X    
XXXX   X
X  X   X
X  X   X
```

This is probably beyond my league because I'm a newbie to c++ and coding in general, however I enjoy messing around with code so its something I wanted to try.

My idea is to make a switch statement that loops through every letter and replaces each letter with the corresponding letter output. However I can't figure out how I would initialize the infinite amount of possible characters the user inputs.

Is there a way to make the input a string and then translate the string into individual char types? From then I can just loop through each character and use the switch statement to switch it out. Also is there a way to count how many characters there are so I can use that to make the loop? For example in python I could just use len("string") and it would give an integer value. Is there anything like that in C++?

I know there is probably a lot simpler and cleaner ways to go about this project, but I'm very limited to the little knowledge I know right now.

Any input would be awesome, thanks.

Comment: What does "initialize the infinite amount of possible characters" mean?

Comment: I mean if I allow the user to input a string with no restriction on how many characters he/she can input it can essentially be as long as he or she wants. I want to use a switch statement that corresponds each character to the output of that character shape, but I need to initialize those characters the user inputted first, don't I? How can I do that when he/she can essentially input as long of a string as she want.

Comment: What do you mean by "initialize"? You need to get the user to input a string, and loop over the characters, and have a switch statement for each character. (Well, that's one possible way of doing it)

Comment: Yeah I realize that after your first answer. But before you replied my thought process was the count every character one by one, not using a string. I wasnt familiar with string operations yet, but you cleared that up for me

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make the input a string

Yes, and it sounds like you already know how to do this part.

> and then translate the string into individual char types?

Yes, if `str` is a variable holding the string, and `i` is the index of the character you want to get, then `str[i]` is that character. (Remember the first character is at index 0)

> Also is there a way to count how many characters there are so I can use that to make the loop?

Yes, if `str` is a variable holding the string, then use `str.length()` (assuming it's a `string` rather than a C-style array of characters).

> For example in python I could just use len("string") and it would give an integer value. Is there anything like that in C++?

See above.